# Python IRC Log Bot

Tags: python, irc

I am looking to start a new project to get my feet wet with Python. I have an IRC channel and would like to have a bot that maintains a log and will spit out x lines of messages when prompted, but I am not sure where to start on writing something like this.

I see [this](http://travismccrea.com/2010/02/write-a-basic-python-irc-bot/) tutorial, and I think that will get me started on the bot itself, but I'm not sure where to go next for the logging functionality. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: To perform the logging functionality I would just keep a simple list of say the last 100 lines and any other lines past that I would push to a file. [Python File I/O](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: I'd look for a higher-level tutorial. Doing IRC with raw sockets and explicit command parsing isn't the hardest thing in the world, but it's not what I'd do to get started. Either grab a skeleton bot or bot framework like SupyBot, or use a library like `irclib` or `twisted.IRCClient`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you've written a dispatch function that calls an appropriate handler for each kind of message, and a send function that formats and sends messages appropriately.

The handlers could look something like this:

```
MAX_LINES = 100

channel_logs = defaultdict(list)

def handle_public_message(user, channel, msg):
    log = logs[channel]
    log.append((user, msg))
    if len(log) > MAX_LINES:
        log.pop(0)
    if msg.partition(' ')[0].lower() == 'dumplog':
        dumplog(log, channel)

def handle_private_message(user, channel, msg):
    if msg.partition(' ')[0].lower() == 'dumplog':
        dumplog(logs[channel], channel, user)

def dumplog(log, channel, user=None):
    for line in log:
        send_msg(line, channel, user)
```

That's all there is to it.

If you want to get fancy, you could write a class that wraps up the "list that only keeps the last 100 append" thing, make it a write-through cache that stores to disk, add a way to request just 20 lines instead of 100, etc.

You could also put more bot-specific functionality in, like handling commands in a more standardized way. But really, you're better off getting a bot framework for that.

In fact, I would strongly recommend that you not start your first project dealing with raw sockets and command parsing. You'll spend far more time debugging tedious and annoying problems instead of dealing with your actual code. Other options include:

- A full bot with Python "AI" plugins, like [`supybot`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/supybot/).
- A skeleton bot with "add your own code here" comments, of which you can find about 3000 from a quick search.
- The `twisted` framework's [`IRCClient`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.words.protocols.irc.IRCClient.html) protocol. Look at tutorials like [this one](http://eflorenzano.com/blog/2008/11/16/writing-markov-chain-irc-bot-twisted-and-python/) to see how much higher-level and simpler everything is.
- [`irclib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/irc).